# install kartik-v editable in Yii2

Tags: php, github, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm new in Yii 2!
I install the kartik grid in my basic yii and create a grid with no problem .
now I want to use

> kartik\grid\EditableColumn

but it needs :

> \kartik\editable\Editable

i insatll the Editable via composer and now i cas see that directory in my vendor file :
[my vendor file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IdzF.png)

now the system gives me this Error again :

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> The class '\kartik\editable\Editable' was not found and is required
>   for GridView EditableColumn.
>
> Please ensure you have installed the 'yii2-editable' extension. To
>   install, you can run this console command from your application root:
>
> php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-editable: "@dev"

and my code :

```
//morecodes
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider'   => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn'],
            'id',
            'countrydate',
            'countryCode',
//more codes
```

can you guys help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

Add `use kartik\editable\Editable;` to the top of the view. It appearse the `Editable` view widget extends the base helper widget. Since Yii2 does not treat views as classes, and thus no namespace, use of classes have to be declared at the beginning / inline of the view's logic.